# Magento 1.9 Custom invoice pdf pushing totals onto new page

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

Hi guys the totals block in my invoice pdf keeps going to a new page, even though there is room on the previous page (Figure 1 is totals block on new page and Figure2 is previous page):

Figure 1

[image: totals new page]

Figure 2

[image: previous page]

Code in Abstract.php I believe prints out the totals block:

```
public function drawLineBlocks(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, array $draw, array $pageSettings = array())
{
    foreach ($draw as $itemsProp) {
        if (!isset($itemsProp['lines']) || !is_array($itemsProp['lines'])) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invalid draw line data. Please define "lines" array.'));
        }
        $lines  = $itemsProp['lines'];
        $height = isset($itemsProp['height']) ? $itemsProp['height'] : 10;

        if (empty($itemsProp['shift'])) {
            $shift = 0;
            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                $maxHeight = 0;
                foreach ($line as $column) {
                    $lineSpacing = !empty($column['height']) ? $column['height'] : $height;
                    if (!is_array($column['text'])) {
                        $column['text'] = array($column['text']);
                    }
                    $top = 0;
                    foreach ($column['text'] as $part) {
                        $top += $lineSpacing;
                    }

                    $maxHeight = $top > $maxHeight ? $top : $maxHeight;
                }
                $shift += $maxHeight;
            }
            $itemsProp['shift'] = $shift;
        }

        if ($this->y - $itemsProp['shift'] < 190) {
            $this->footer($page);
            $page = $this->newPage($pageSettings);
        }

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $maxHeight = 0;
            foreach ($line as $column) {
                $fontSize = empty($column['font_size']) ? 10 : $column['font_size'];
                if (!empty($column['font_file'])) {
                    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath($column['font_file']);
                    $page->setFont($font, $fontSize);
                } else {
                    $fontStyle = empty($column['font']) ? 'regular' : $column['font'];
                    switch ($fontStyle) {
                        case 'bold':
                            $font = $this->_setFontBold($page, $fontSize);
                            break;
                        case 'italic':
                            $font = $this->_setFontItalic($page, $fontSize);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $font = $this->_setFontRegular($page, $fontSize);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (!is_array($column['text'])) {
                    $column['text'] = array($column['text']);
                }

                $lineSpacing = !empty($column['height']) ? $column['height'] : $height;
                $top = 0;
                foreach ($column['text'] as $part) {
                    if ($this->y - $lineSpacing < 190) {
                        $page = $this->newPage($pageSettings);
                    }

                    $feed = $column['feed'];
                    $textAlign = empty($column['align']) ? 'left' : $column['align'];
                    $width = empty($column['width']) ? 0 : $column['width'];
                    switch ($textAlign) {
                        case 'right':
                            if ($width) {
                                $feed = $this->getAlignRight($part, $feed, $width, $font, $fontSize);
                            }
                            else {
                                $feed = $feed - $this->widthForStringUsingFontSize($part, $font, $fontSize);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'center':
                            if ($width) {
                                $feed = $this->getAlignCenter($part, $feed, $width, $font, $fontSize);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    $page->drawText($part, $feed, $this->y-$top, 'UTF-8');
                    $top += $lineSpacing;
                }

                $maxHeight = $top > $maxHeight ? $top : $maxHeight;
            }
            $this->y -= $maxHeight;
        }
    }

    return $page;
}
}
```

Comment: have you customized in "Abstract.php" file?

Comment: Abdul indeed I have. I have an 150 high footer so in the function in the question I made the lines $this->y - $lineSpacing < 190 and $this->y - $itemsProp['shift'] < 190

Comment: If you are trying to default then it working fine or not?

Comment: Default would take the lines down to 15 thus footer would cover it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added following to drawLinesBlock function in abstract.php:

```
$isTotalsBlock = isset($itemsProp['isTotals']) ? 151 : 205;
```

Then used this variable here:

```
 if ($this->y - $lineSpacing < $isTotalsBlock)
 $this->y - $itemsProp['shift'] < $isTotalsBlock
```

And added following to InsertTotals function (To the linesBlock array):

```
 'isTotals' => true,
```

So rather than a static value I am via this catering for a 55 height block i have added. Thus, if the totals block is being drawn then it can go to 151 in the Y-coordinate else 205( 150 footer and 55 block)